# Passing Enumeration value using Jacob bridge (COM/ActiveX)

Tags: java, com, activex, jacob

Does anyone know if there's a way to pass an enumeration value using Jacob?

```
ComObj.ComEnum.enumVal1
ComObj.ComEnum.enumVal2
```

I'd like to pass `enumVal1` or `enumVal2` as a `Variant`.

```
o.invoke("Action",new Variant("enumVal1"));   \\just pseudo code
```

Answer (score 0):

The enum values are available in the Object Browser of the Macro Editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The OP seems to be asking about how to make the actual call... of which obtaining the underlying values (as shown by @ChadiEM) is be one part.

[I found a post on the subject](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s225/enumerations.htm) which says `the values ... correspond to internally stored numbers` and `An enumeration in VBA is always of data type Long`.

So, with this info and values , it's simply a matter of passing a `Variant` with the value as a `long`.  For example:

```
o.invoke("Action",new Variant(34L));
```

I'm sure there's a way to get actual "Enumeration" data structures, but this was good enough for me.